Bitcoin Core release verification Umbrel Home
As it is highly recommendable to verify the release software of Bitcoin Core, I am wondering how this works with Umbrel Home. I now have the Bitcoin Core on an SSD drive which works fine, but I would like to change to the Umbrel Home server. However, if I cannot verify the Bitcoin Core software, I would have to trust Umbrel, that does not sit right with me.
Who can help me with this question?
